# Sublime Text 2 horizontal scroll selecting text

Tags: sublimetext2

Whenever i try to select line of text that is longer and i need to scroll to right to select it Sublime text scrolls back to left.
I tried deleting all plugins but it looks like a default sublime text behavior.
Does this happen to everyone else and can this be changed?

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't happen to me. Selecting and scrolling over keeps me on the right. You can also put your cursor at the front of the line, hold shift and hit the end key. You should be on the right with the line highlighted.

Extra: If you want to highlight a line and stay on the left, triple click the line.